# How to insert data into MongoDB with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

First I've set the default by setting the database connection to be mongodb.

```
'mongodb' => [
      'driver'   => 'mongodb',
      'host'     => 'localhost',
      'username' => 'dofUser',
      'password' => 'dofPass',
      'database' => 'dof',
  ],
```

Apps/models/user

```
   <?php
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $collection = 'user';
    //$user = user::all();
}
```

and Router

```
        Route::post('/register', function()
{
   $user->model('User', 'App\Models\User');
   $user = new User;

 $user = User::create(array(
'username' => Input::get('username'),
'fullname' => Input::get('fullname'),
'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
'gender' => Input::get('gender'),
'month' => Input::get('month'),
'day' => Input::get('day'),
'year' => Input::get('year'),
'phone' => Input::get('phone'),
'email' => Input::get('email-act'),
'agree' => Input::get('agree')
));

    return redirect('/login');

});
```

But I submit the browser is blank. Not redirect to login
in MongoDB I just make a Collection named user.

Comment: I don't believe that you need to use both
 `$user = new User;`
and
 `$user = User::create(array(....` The latter is a facade. Also, did you set  either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, "as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment." [link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

Comment: I do not know, it should be how?

Comment: `class User extends Eloquent { protected $fillable = array('username','fullname'....);`

Comment: The Router how?
Sorry I am a novice--I use laravel 5

Comment: You wrote "But I submit the browser is blank." can you look in storage/logs/ to see if there are relevant errors?

Comment: class User extends Eloquent { protected $fillable = array('username','fullname'....); –
where connect to collection ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create User again. You can do like this.

```
 $user = new User();

 $user->'username' = Input::get('username');
 $user->'fullname' = Input::get('fullname');
 $user ->'password' = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

 $user->save();

 return redirect('/login');
```

You can check the following tutorial for learn how to insert data to mongodb using Laravel.

[Laravel with MongoDB CURD operations - Configuration](http://laralessons.blogspot.com/2018/06/laravel-with-mongodb-curd-operations.html)

[Laravel with MongoDB CURD operations - Save data](http://laralessons.blogspot.com/2018/06/laravel-with-mongodb-curd-operations_11.html)

Check your login routes return something.
Please post your method related to the login route.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this tutorial in youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltFSEUCCD_4

it teach how to add data into laravel by mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck "return redirect('/login');"